# Xcode: URL Types: Icon?

Tags: iphone, xcode, url

The Xcode docs, explain that the `CFBundleURLIconFile` key contains the name of the icon image file (minus the extension) to be used for displaying URLs of this type.

My remaining questions are:

1. What icon image should I use? Like, if the URL type is for another app, should I use that app's app icon?
2. What size(s)? If many sizes, how do I name them so that the sizes are used correctly?
3. Where is it displayed? I'm wondering for an iPhone app.

Answer (score 2):

1. Apple does not specify this specifically, but my interpretation is that it should be an Icon representing the application which should/will open/handle URLs of this type.
2. On OS X, the normal approach would be to use an Icon File (.icns).  I suspect you should try that on your iOS app.  If that doesn't work, duplicate the naming scheme of the the standard app icon files.
3. Try viewing a PDF in Safari on iOS. If you have iBooks, it should show a button saying "Open in iBooks" and shows an icon next to it.  This icon is the icon you would be setting.

I hope this is thorough enough to answer your questions.  If not, please explain what needs clarification.

Comment: XCode 4 has a handy URL Types helper now, where you can just drag an icon image into the dialog and you're all set.

Comment: Seems I can drop an image into the URL Types helper (in addition to .icns file). I assume a dropped image should have a minimum resolution, but none is given.

Comment: any answers found by this topic? how to set icon and image?

Comment: @AbbasFatullaev check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937374/how-can-i-add-image-in-url-type-info-plist