# How can i add Image in URL Type info-plist?

Tags: ios, xcode, info-plist

[image: How can i add image in URL Type]

I can't able to add image (image already added in Assets.xcassets) in URL Type in info List.
please help me in this, i search regarding URL Type but i did't get any solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to add images to URL Type, you need to add images in the project folder, and then type the name of the image in there, for some reason asset's images are not working here. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks shabir, you are right assets image are not working.